# Can I get the steps inside workflow only?

Tags: filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

I am trying to get all the steps inside a particular workflow ONLY in FileNet Process Engine. But no luck getting it. I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve is available in the API because I looked for days but cannot see it.

Here is my code
       String workflowName = "Sample workflow 1";

```
    String[] workClassNames = myPESession.fetchWorkClassNames(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < workClassNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(workClassNames[i]);
    }


    // Launch Workflow VWStepElement
    VWStepElement stepElement = myPESession.createWorkflow(workflowName);
    System.out.println(stepElement.getWorkflowName());
    System.out.println(stepElement.getSubject());
    System.out.println(stepElement.getComment());
    System.out.println(stepElement.getStepDescription());
    System.out.println("Parameters");

    String[] a = stepElement.getParameterNames();
       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       {
           if (a[i] != null)
           {
               Object _parameterValue = stepElement.getParameterValue(a[i]);
               System.out.println("\t" + a[i] + "=" + _parameterValue);
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is static part that is the same for any instance of particular workflow. Thus you should obtain it from the workflow definition, not the running workflow instance.

You should start with [`VWWorkflowDefinition`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.java.doc/filenet/vw/api/VWWorkflowDefinition.html), iterate through each map obtained using [`getMaps()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.java.doc/filenet/vw/api/VWWorkflowDefinition.html#getMaps()) and then obtain the steps from [`VWMapDefinition`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.java.doc/filenet/vw/api/VWMapDefinition.html) using [`getSteps()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.java.doc/filenet/vw/api/VWMapDefinition.html#getSteps()).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
VWWorkflowDefinition defn = peSession.fetchWorkflowDefinition(workSpaceId, workflowIdentifier, convert);
VWMapDefinition vwMapDefinition = defn.getMap(workflowname);
VWMapNode[] mapNode = vwMapDefinition.getSteps()//Gets all of the steps contained in this map.
```

then iterate the mapNode.